# Object is possibly null error Typescript when doing comparison

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple sort:

```
dataCopy.sort((a: Data, b: Data) => {
  if (a[label] === null || b[label] === null) return 0;
  if (direction === "desc")
    return a[label] > b[label] ? 1 : -1;
  return 0;
});
```

The "Data" type is:

```
export type Data = {
  [key: string]: string | number | null;
};
```

I check if a[label] and b[label] are both null and I still get the error "Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)". It seems to only happen with the > and < operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just not smart enough to see that you checked.  BTW you didn't post where `label` was coming from, but assuming that's not the problem, try this:

```
dataCopy.sort((a: Data, b: Data) => {
  const aLabel = a[label];
  const bLabel = b[label];
  if (aLabel === null || bLabel === null) return 0;
  if (direction === "desc")
    return aLabel > bLabel ? 1 : -1;
  return 0;
});
```

Sometimes you have to factor things out so that TypeScript can see that you've checked for conditions like `=== null`.

Comment: Thanks, a good lesson to learn. It can tell if I check the variable aLabel, but not if I have checked a[label].